# A comparison of HTML based slide systems?

Tags: html, system, slide, s5

I started using S5 for a presentation and I quite like it so far. However, I have seen a few other systems being mentioned such as S9 (which is, as I understand it, an extension of S5), Slidy and a few others.

I'd be intrested what the differences are between all of these. I'd also like a motivation to why you think one of them are better?

I'd also like to know what the main advantages of using S5-generators such as Sphinx. I'm currently learning Ruby so that vista is open as well.

I find S5 very easy to use but I want to know what the alternatives bring.

Comment: "which ones are easier to use" is very subjective. Please recheck the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), your question isn't really on topic here.

Comment: You are fully correct, I'll try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Paul Rouget's DZSlides](http://paulrouget.com/dzslides/) as it

- It allows for anything in the presentation supported by modern browsers (HTML5)
- You can easily embed presentations into websites (see his demo presentation)
- Has a nice full-screen mode (just press F11 and off you go)